Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a - b \sin t)^2 + 1} \, dt $ Connections to Elliptic Integrals?
I am investigating the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a - b \sin t)^2 + 1} \, dt$$
where $a > 0$ and $b>0$. This integral arises in a context involving periodic functions, and I suspect it has a connection to elliptic integrals due to its structure.
When we have $a=0$, for specific integer values of $b$ the integral is $4 \, \text{EllipticE}(-b^2)$, and for general b it is $2 \left(\text{EllipticE}(-b^2) + \sqrt{1 + b^2} \, \text{EllipticE}\left(\frac{b^2}{1 + b^2}\right)\right).$
But even for simple special cases like $a=1,b=1$ and $a=1,b=2$ CAS is not helping. I tried some trig transformations without any success.
Has this integral or a closely related one been evaluated in mathematical literature, or is it too challenging at this moment?
Thanks

See here and here for details on computing$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-(a+b\sin t)^2},dt\text{ and }\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{b+(1-a\cos t)^2},dt$$The techniques shown there may be adaptable here.

Here's a solution based on Parcly Taxel's evaluation of $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{b+(1-a\cos t)^2}\,dt$; most of the steps in the linked post are indicated by $(1),(2),(3)$. Let

$c=\dfrac{a+i}b$
$A=\dfrac{1+\lvert c\rvert^2+\left\lvert c^2-1\right\rvert}{2\Re c}$
$\left(A_1,A_2\right)=\left(A^2-2A\Re c+\lvert c\rvert^2,A^2\lvert c\rvert^2-2A\Re c+1\right)$
$B=\dfrac{A_2}{A_1}$
$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(cA-1,c-A,2b\sqrt{A_1}\sqrt{A^2-1}\right)$
$(\mu,\nu)=\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{B+1}},\dfrac1{\sqrt{A^2-1}}\right)$


$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+(a-b\sin t)^2} \, dt \\
&= \left\{\color{red}{\int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^0}+\int_0^\tfrac{3\pi}2\right\} \sqrt{1+(a-b\cos t)^2} \, dt & t\to t+\frac\pi2 \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+(a-b\cos t)^2} \, dt & \color{red}{t\to2\pi+t} \\
&= 2 \int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+(a-b\cos t)^2} \, dt & \text{symmetry} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}= 2b \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{(c-u)\left(c^*-u\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du & u=\cos t \\
&= 2b \sqrt{A^2-1} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{(\alpha+\beta v)\left(\alpha^*+\beta^*v\right)}}{(A+v)^2 \sqrt{1-v^2}} \, dv & u=\frac{1+Av}{A+v} \\
&\stackrel{(2)}= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\gamma\sqrt{B+v^2}}{(A+v)^2\sqrt{1-v^2}} \, dv \\
&\stackrel{(3)}= \int_0^1 \frac{2\gamma\,dv}{\sqrt{B+v^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}} -  \int_0^1 \frac{4\gamma A^2\,dv}{\left(A^2-v^2\right)\sqrt{B+v^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}} \\
&\qquad + 2\gamma\left(A^2+B\right) \int_0^1 \frac{A^2+v^2}{\left(A^2-v^2\right)^2\sqrt{B+v^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}} \, dv \\
&= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{2\gamma\mu\,dw}{\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2w}} - \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{4\gamma A^2 \mu \nu^2\,dw}{\left(1+\nu^2\sin^2w\right)\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2w}} \\
&\qquad + 2\gamma\mu \nu^2\left(\frac1{\mu^2}+\frac3{\nu^2}+2\right) \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{1+2\nu^2-\nu^2\sin^2w}{\left(1+\nu^2\sin^2w\right)^2 \sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2w}} \, dw & v=\cos w\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
\implies 
I &= 2\gamma \mu K(\mu) - 2\gamma\mu \nu^2\left(\frac1{\mu^2}+\frac3{\nu^2}+2\right) \Pi\left(-\nu^2,\mu\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac{4\gamma}\mu \left(1+\nu^2\right)\left(\mu^2+\nu^2\right) \underbrace{\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dw}{\left(1+\nu^2\sin^2w\right)^2 \sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2w}}}_{=J(\mu,\nu)}
\end{align*}$$
Mathematica can compute this last indefinite integral, though its output involves several incomplete EIs in terms of a complex argument, which can be further reduced to
$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{2\left(1+\nu^2\right)\left(\mu^2+\nu^2\right)\,dx}{\left(1+\nu^2\sin^2x\right)^2\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2x}} &= \nu^2E\left(x\mid\mu\right) - \left(\mu^2+\nu^2\right) F\left(x\mid\mu\right) \\
&\qquad + \left(2\nu^2+\nu^4+3\mu^2+2\mu^2\nu^2\right) \Pi\left(-\nu^2; x\mid\mu\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac{\nu^4}2 \frac{\sin(2x)\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2x}}{1+\nu^2\sin^2x} + C
\end{align*}$$
It follows that
$$J(\mu,\nu) = \frac{\nu^2 E(\mu) - \left(\mu^2+\nu^2\right) K(\mu) + \left(2\nu^2+\nu^4+3\mu^2+2\mu^2\nu^2\right) \Pi\left(-\nu^2,\mu\right)}{2\left(1+\nu^2\right)\left(\mu^2+\nu^2\right)}$$
and hence
$$\boxed{I = \frac{2\gamma\nu^2}\mu \left[E(\mu) - K(\mu) + \left(1+\nu^2\right) \Pi\left(-\nu^2,\mu\right)\right]}$$
This result was confirmed numerically for randomly chosen $(a,b)\in(0,100)^2$.

I tried: {2 \[Gamma] v^2/\[Mu]*(EllipticE[\[Mu]] -                 EllipticK[\[Mu]] + (1 + v^2)*                 EllipticPi[-v^2, Sqrt[\[Mu]]]) /. \[Mu] -> 1/Sqrt[              B + 1] /. v -> 1/Sqrt[A^2 - 1] /. \[Gamma] ->             2 b Sqrt[A1]*Sqrt[A^2 - 1] /. B -> A2/A1 /.          A1 -> A^2 - 2 A Re[c] + Abs[c]^2 /.         A2 -> A^2*Abs[c]^2 - 2 A Re[c] + 1 /.        A -> (1 + Abs[c]^2 + Abs[c^2 - 1])/(2 Re[c]) /.       c -> (a + I)/b /. a -> 2 /. b -> 2 // N,   NIntegrate[   Sqrt[b + (1 - a Cos[t])^2] /. a -> 2 /. b -> 2, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]} gives: {16.3346, 13.3925} ?

@MariuszIwaniuk (1) OP's integrand is Sqrt[1+(a-b Sin[t])^2] but can be replaced with Sqrt[1+(a-b Cos[t])^2]; either way, not the same as Sqrt[b+(1-a Cos[t])^2] which is addressed in the linked question. (2) To verify in Mathematica, the elliptic integral expressions should read EllipticE[\[Mu]^2], EllipticK[\[Mu]^2], and EllipticPi[-\[Nu]^2, \[Mu]^2] (recall M's convention to use the parameter, not the modulus)

By cutting bounds, shifting and changing variable ($\sin t\mapsto x)$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{(a-b\sin t)^2+1}\ dt=2\int_{0}^{1}(f(a,b,x)+f(-a,b,x))\ dx$$
Where $f(a,b,x)=\frac{\sqrt{b^2x^2+2abx+a^2+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.
I will compute $\int f(a,b,x)\ dx$
Input (Mathematica code):
Integrate[Sqrt[b^2*x^2+2*a*b*x+a^2+1]/Sqrt[1-x^2],x]

Output:

The only thing left is to compute the limit of antiderivative to $1$ and $0$, this is not simple at all but I will leave it to you, as the main problem-finding connection with elliptic integrals is done.
It is known that a whole class of antiderivative of quadratic function can be represented as elementary functions combine with elliptic integrals. A detailed symbolic algorithm to find such antiderivative is given at mathworld (and surely that algorithm is not supposed to be carried out by human, it exists for theory)
comment: I have to use image because the TeXForm is too ugly.

@MariuszIwaniuk Unfortunately, the limit of antiderivative as $x\to 1$ is not $0$, we can't ignore it, so I have to change it back.

It seems simpler to write $1+(a-b x)^2=b^2(x-\alpha ) (x-\beta )$ for the same result

It works if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ just like the OP wanted.
